# View pager content getting hidden by Tablayout in android

Tags: android

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tabs1"
                layout="@layout/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            layout="@layout/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.wokoshop.sony.fragment.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want viewpager to be below tablayout. i have used android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout" but still some content of viewpager getting hide by toolbar and tab layout.

What changes i need to do so it come below TabLayout.